# What is the difference between E-Science Infrastructures and Distributed Computing Infrastructures

Tags: computer-science, grid-computing

What is the difference between eScience infrastructures and grid computing or distributed computing infrastructures? And what are some of their examples.

I can not distinguish them clearly. Is it how a grid is used make it an e-science platform?

Comment: it is just naming conventions and some buzz words. what is your research about?

Comment: @ElYusubov I have to make a system for escience platform to help the researchers

Answer (score 1):

eScience appears to be a British governmental term for Computational Science done on distributed computing systems and the surrounding infrastructure such as databases and the like. The term in the United States is "Cyberinfrastructure"...because it was the 90s and Al Gore was involved. Both appear to be largely governmental terms for specifically governmental projects involving large scale computing involving scientific research.

Comment: I have started a (MS) research project on E-Science platforms. Like you have said, the e-science uses immense datasets for research and relies on large distributed computing systems. I am told the neuGRID is an e-science platform and also the LHC computing grid.
But I found that neuGRID was listed under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects with many others and not under the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Science

I am interested in knowing what other e-science platforms are there as well.